# ImageMagick equivalent to PhotoShop Curves

Tags: imagemagick, curves

I am trying to convert some custom image filters with ImageMagic command line from PhotoShop tutorials. I can manage to work out most of it, but when it comes to "Curves", I can't seem to find any information on how to translate the following using ImageMagic command line.

Image > Adjustments > Curves. Go into the green channel and put the output to 32 and then go to the blue channel and put the output to 110.

I am trying to adjust the colors in the `$img_in` in this example:

```
$img_in = "image.jpg";
$gradient = "convert -size $dim radial-gradient:#f7d9ad-#f0ce9b ";
$c = " $gradient -compose multiply -gravity center -composite ";
exec("convert $img_in $c $img_out");
```

Any help here would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean the minimum output, the maximum output or all outputs - there are two very different answers.

Comment: I Mark. I updated my question with the example. I'm not 100% sure what you mean, but I am trying to change the colors in the original image above - "image.jpg".

Comment: Can you maybe add a screengrab of how Photoshop's Curves dialog looks when you have set the Green channel to 32 please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean you want to set the curves so that the maximum output value of the green channel is 42, you are effectively scaling the green channel by a factor of 42/255. So, if your original inage was, say, white, and your green channel curve looks like this, your image would be more red and blue (i.e. purplish) like this when you reduce the green to 42/255 of its full-scale value.

[image]

then you could achieve the same effect in ImageMagick using the `fx` operator like this:

```
convert -channel green input.jpg -fx "u*42/255" out.jpg
```